# iPad split screen ruins my website

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive website, written in CSS with media queries.

I tested on all devices and it works, however on iPad split screen feature (it splits the screen with ratio of 3:1 I open my website in the 1 area) from some reason it shows the bigger media query, it shows the media query for the iPad size not for the window size, it works great on the iPhone it is the same size as the small split screen.

Here's example of how the code written

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1100px) {
  #icons {
    width: 1024px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 797px) {
  html,
  body {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 730px) and (min-device-width: 450px) {
  .icons {
    margin-left: 12%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 450px) and (min-device-width: 390px) {
  .icons {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 14%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 390px) and (min-device-width: 291px) {
  .icons {
    margin-left: 9%;
    width: 23%;
  }
}
```

Comment: With any example code, we cannot do anything without the HTML. Kindly provide with some HTML please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind i figured it out .
the problem is

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: ...) and (min-device-width:...)
```

it reads the device width instead of the current viewport width, so that what caused the issue fixed it by replacing with `max-width` (hope it doesn't break something else)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ...) and (min-width:...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use max-width instead of max-device-width as device-width means size of device and not the broswer window. Same is for min-device-width